# Directive run code on click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a button with directive and need now on click to call the factory. The problem is when page opened it automatically call code. I need to do this with just one directive.

```
.directive("addcomment",addcomment);

         function addcomment(){
           var addComment = {
                link: link,
                restrict: "E",
                template: '<input type="submit" addcomments class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Send" />'
           };

           return addComment;

           function link(scope, element, attrs){
              //RUN FACTORY
                };  
           }
         }
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Why use a directive? You may as well just call a function in a controller using ng-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    //RUN FACTORY
}
```

you need to bind the factory execution to a click event.

```
function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
        //Run the factory here
    });
};
```

I guess this should work.